# Simple storing of JSON .get results in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Simply, I am trying to create a string array from a json get method. The method returns a List, which comes from an MVC controller method, `JsonResult output(string centreName)` and in my javascript, I have this:

```
    <script src="../../Content/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("#centres").change(function () {
                var _this = jQuery(this);
                var selectedCentre = _this.val();
                $.getJSON("/Centres/output?centreName=" + selectedCentre, 
function(results) {
    // store the results here in a new array, so I can do something with them
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Now all the above code works perfectly fine, I just don't know how to play with the results properly. How do I make a nice "string array[] = results" sort of thing?

**EDIT**

This is the method that needs results as an array of strings:

```
document.getElementById("container2").innerHTML = "";
                        var div;
                        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("centres").value; i++) {
                            div = document.createElement("div");
                            div.className = "class1";
                            div.innerHTML = "Shop " + data[i];
                            div.innerHTML += "<br>";
                            div.innerHTML += "Floor Space: <b>" + spaces[i] + " m2 </b>";
                            div.style.width = "100px";
                            div.style.height = "100px";
                            div.style.padding = "0px";
                            div.style.float = "left";
                            document.getElementById("container2").appendChild(div);
                        }
```

As you can see, I need to iterate through each shop code (data[i]). How do I do this?

Comment: If your webservice returns an array of data, `results` already is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store it in a nice "string array[]".  The .NET JSON serializer should serialize your JSON for you, which is basically an array-like structure.  Just access the results directly.

```
$.getJSON("/Centres/output?centreName=" + selectedCentre, function(results) {
    var data = results;

    // You can iterate over the data (or results directly) and manipulate it as needed
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On json universe a list and an array is the same. There is no specific implementation for `List`, you just have arrays. Probably `results` is already an array of objects unless the server is returning a single object.

If you're trying to extract a specific field from the object, you could use a [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) statement to iterate the array and get necessary information.

```
$.each(results, function(index, element) {
  // your logic here
}
```

**EDIT**

if `results` is an array of strings and you need to convert them in a single string, you could use `join` method

```
var results = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var joinedString = results.join();
//joinedString = 'Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango'
```

if you need to pick a different separator you could use this approach

```
var results = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var joinedString = results.join(' and ');
//joinedString = 'Banana and Orange and Apple and Mango'
```

Comment: But how would I iterate through an array of, for example, var data = results? I'm thinking something along the lines of for(int i = 0; i < results.Counts; i++) { string whatever += data[I] }

Comment: @barnacle.m: take my code literally, `.each` is the way to iterate over `results` no need to assign it to `data`. Is results an array of strings? Could you post `results` structure?

Comment: results is a comes from my JsonResult method, and in that method I return Json(shops, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); where shops is a List<string>. The javascript function that needs this array needs something along the lines of results[i].

Comment: In that case you'll want `$.each(results[0], ...`

Comment: I'm posting my javascript method in my original post so you guys can see what I'm trying to do. Thanks for all your patience!